# Methods to calculate $P(a \leq X^2 \leq b)$ given the pdf of X?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a continuous distribution X with a pdf of $f(x), x \in [-1, 1]$.

So I integrate $f(x)$ to get the cdf of X.

I must calculate:

$$P(\frac{1}{3} \leq X^2 \leq 1)$$

It seems a crude way to do this is to calculate it by cases $X < 0, X \geq 0$:

$$= P(\big[-1 \leq X \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \big] \cup \big[\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \leq X \leq 1 \big])$$

Since the intervals are non-overlapping, the events are independent hence:

$$= P(-1 \leq X \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) + P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \leq X \leq 1)$$

And I can use the cdf of X to solve ie.:

$$= \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} f(x) dx + \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{1} f(x) dx $$

However this seems a crude way to solve it. Is there a better way?

In particular I would like to know:

1) Can I make the calculation without having to translate the intervals of $X^2$ back to $X$ by cases?

2) If so, can I make still the calculation using the pdf of X or do I need to calculate the pdf of $X^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pdf of $Y = X^2$ is easy to calculate.

If $y<0$, then the equation $y = x^2$ has no real solutions; hence, $f_Y(y)=0$.

If $y>0$, then $y=x^2$ has two solutions, $x_1 = \sqrt{y}$ and $x_2 = -\sqrt{y}$.

Now, $y=g(x)=x^2$ and $g'(x)=2x$. Hence by the transformation of variables formula:
$$
f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}}\left[f_X(\sqrt{y}) + f_X(-\sqrt{y})\right],  & y>0 \\
0, & y<0 
\end{cases}
$$